# KEDA autoscaling based on QueueLength and CPU usage

Tags: spring, kubernetes, rabbitmq, keda

Hello everyone hope you all doing well. I have a `Spring Boot` app that consumes from `Rabbitmq`. I deployed it on `Kubernetes` and I configured the autoscaling based on the queue length after the queue size passes, 100 for example, message a new pod got created.

What I want to make the scaling up more efficient like not always scale up for example I can have 110 messages in the queue but the first `pod` is able to handle this because the CPU usage or memory or both are not that high. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me to achieve this.